# How can I add and store data in a UITableView?

Tags: xcode, tableview, cells

I'm creating an app that inserts values to a tableview. I also want to add the timestamp on when the value is added to the table. The scenario would be this:

1. I write some random text in a text field.
2. I push a button
3. The text from the text field is saved in the table together with the time I tapped the button.
4. Done.

Answer (score 1):

```
(NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                            NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
}

 (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:field1.text];
    [array addObject:field2.text];
    [array addObject:field3.text];
    [array addObject:field4.text];
    [array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
    [array release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large your data is, you can store it in a plist, or sqlite3. 
Here's a link that might be useful:
http://www.bogotobogo.com/XcodeSDK-Chapter10.html